# VB.net setting values to labels inside a backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

My code works but I am in doubt of what I did because i set CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false which I think would give some side-effects to my backgroundworker. Here is my sample code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    System.Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

End Sub

Private Sub go_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles go.Click

    Try
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy <> True Then
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
            resetevent.Set()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Do

    Label1.Text = x
Label2.Text = Label1.Text
Label3.Text = Label2.Tex
Label4.Text = Label3.Text
Label5.Text = Label4.Text

    x+=1
    Loop While (x < 100)


End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Try



    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_Completed(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Is there a way for me to set values to labels inside a backgroundworker without setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to False? Because I have experienced some bugs with my program where the loop suddenly stops even if the counter limit has not been reached yet.

Comment: FUTURE READERS: using CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls does not make any sense; it is just a help while debugging codes. Nobody is expecting you to put a flag avoiding errors to be triggered into a production code. You have to make sure that you don't call GUI/Main thread from the background one (by relying on any of the alternatives suggested in the answers below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the method

```
  Private Sub setLabelTxt(ByVal text As String, ByVal lbl As Label)
    If lbl.InvokeRequired Then
        lbl.Invoke(New setLabelTxtInvoker(AddressOf setLabelTxt), text, lbl)
    Else
        lbl.Text = text
    End If
End Sub
Private Delegate Sub setLabelTxtInvoker(ByVal text As String, ByVal lbl As Label)
```

and call setLabelTxt in DoWork.

**EDIT:**
I will add the explanation a bit later with references as I am a bit busy right now. 
I had your problem also and this worked for me.

**EDIT:**

"**The way to safely access controls from worker threads is via delegation.**
First you test the InvokeRequired property of the control, which will tell you whether or not you can safely access the control. InvokeRequired is one of the few members of the Control class that is thread-safe, so you can access it anywhere. If the property is True then an invocation is required to access the control because the current method is executing on a thread other than the one that owns the control's Handle.

The invocation is performed by calling the control's Invoke or BeginInvoke method. You create a delegate, which is an object that contains a reference to a method. It is good practice to make that a reference to the current method. You then pass that delegate to the Invoke or BeginInvoke method. That will essentially call the referenced method again, this time on the thread that owns the control's Handle."

Source: **jmcilhinney** post **Accessing Controls from Worker Threads** 
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads

I can't explain better than him as I'm a noob also

Comment: does this work with real-time loop updating? as i want to update my label value for each loop until the loop ends.

Comment: You should explain the reason why this works and what are the advantages/disadvantages. Also, the OP is mainly concerned about using CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls. Why he shouldn't use it? You have to improve this answer quite a lot.

Comment: @MarcIntes I have explained it to you in my answer: this is basically a "trick" to call the GUI thread and thus to scape from the backgroundworker thread (kind of shortcut to "backgroundworker complet"). If you http requests do not take too long (and the GUI does not freezes), you wouldn't need to rely on the backgroundworker at all (and keep jumping between threads what is what this code does).

Comment: my GUI freezes without backgroundworker while making http requests, i need to use background worker.

Comment: @varocarbas I promise I will edit the answer with all the information later today. Meanwhile here is the link that helped me when I had this problem http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads

Comment: @MarcIntes if you need to use the backgroundworker you can rely on this approach (or as suggested: completed or progresschange). But understand what you are doing, this was the whole point of my clarification.

Comment: I don't need to read about what your code does, I know that: you are forcing to call the given function from the main/GUI thread no matter where you are (in the background thread, for example). But this does not represent to stop considering the background thread anyway and a constant jump between threads. All this is what I thought you should include in this answer. Also bear in mind that the OP is asking if using CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls is acceptable or not, what you are not even answering. Do whatever you want but I think that this answer needs quite a few improvements.

Comment: I need the values from the labels before making a httpwebrequest as i would pass the the values needed in making httpwebrequest to the label and use those values in making a httpwebrequest. So that my GUI would explain on how the httpwebrequest has been done through the label values per httpwebrequest.

Comment: @varocarbas the link was for OP

Comment: Ah! then better don't add my nick with a heading "@" :)

Comment: I have tried this method just now but only using one label and it works. But my question is i am gonna be updating 10 labels at once does it mean i would create a method for each label being called in the backgroundworker? Will this not affect the performance of my backgroundworker?

Comment: @MarcIntes I think that I have been pretty descriptive and have explained the point clearly. These other two answer have also contributed to improve your ideas on what all this is about. But you don't seen to want to get the ideas (,and implement everything by your own) what all this is about, but to get a specific solution for a specific problem (which you haven't defined). I am not sure that I am starting to like all this too much.

Comment: @MarcIntes you don't have to create a method for each label because you give the text and the label you want to update as parameters to the method

Comment: @MarcIntes "not affect the performance of my backgroundworker"? The backgroundworker will be waiting for you to finish updating any GUI element. Well... I think that I have explained a lot and don't like certain kind of attitudes. You have got your information, now I will delete my answer (intending to not answer OP's showing a behaviour I don't think that is defendable and this thing of keep asking and asking and forgetting about the original question and getting a bit of knowledge from here and bit of knowledge from there... is something I don't think that should be promoted in SO).

Comment: I get it now thanks. I hope this would cure the unexpected stops of my backgroundworker thread. As I have tried setting the loop limit to 1,000, it won't reach to the 1,000th loop and it stops and does nothing. HttpWebRequest could not be causing this as I have set a trapping exception that display a messagebox whenever it fails a request and continues to loop.

Comment: @Ric A small (+1) appraise for your effort. I think that your answers need quite a few improvements but seeing this kind of OPs keep asking and asking and not appraising others' help is something which I don't like at all.

Comment: @varocarbas +1 for your great effort. This is my first answer on SO so I was excited to be able to answer a question. That would be my excuse for the lack of insight I give.

Comment: you cannot +1 what does not exist (deleted my answer) :). You don't need to excuse for anything. If you consider that my comments are worthy, just bring them into account and update your answer accordingly. In general, it is a good thing to answer what the OP is asking (CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls) and give some kind of justification of what you proposed. But well... everyone is here to learn, if you have the right attitude you will not find any problem.

Comment: first answer? your profile seems to indicate other thing?!Anyway... I was about to write a code on this lines when you wrote your answer and thus became really handy (for me to explain the point and for the OP to get the working bit he was interested in).

Comment: @varocarbas I didn't count the answers to my own questions :) I will update my answer on your points. This would be good learning exercise for me! Back to work now

Comment: No problem. All this are learning exercises for all of us (SO asking/answering is an excellent training). Don't want to be too insistent on this front (because doesn't really matter) but, to honor the truth, this is your third answer, one of the previous ones was an answer to your own question but the other one not (the first one, actually). In any case... you have been quite lucky to get involved in this situation and hopefully will help this OP to have a different behaviour in the future (I will not be helping him again in the short time just to make sure).

Answer (score 3):

During the `ProgressChanged` event, you can access the UI as it states in the MSDN documentation:

> The ProgressChanged event handler executes on the thread that created the BackgroundWorker.

Thus, if you created the `BackGroundWorker` on the UI thread, you can update the UI, eliminating your need to `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls`

Source:

[MSDN backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx)

Comment: I am not sure about what this answer gives on top of mine; but in any case, the OP thinks that using CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls is acceptable and just want to confirm if this is the case or not (what you are not even mentioning, just suggesting an alternative). By doing what you propose (exactly the same than what I proposed: don't call GUI from backgroundworker thread) he would have to change his code completely. In summary: I am not sure about the exact applicability of this answer to the current problem/concerns.

Comment: By using CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls, he is effectively suppressing any cross thread calls to the UI, which may be desirable (I don't really see how though). I believe that this is the correct way to use the BackGroundWorker and as you stated CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls '...it assumes that this flag is only used for debugging purposes' and '... a temporary help while fixing a code'. This would improve things a lot and is not just a temporary fix.

Comment: IF the op feels this answer is inappropriate, then I will gladly remove it. After all, I was only trying to be helpful but if this is not the case then so be it.

Comment: Sure you were trying to be helpful... and this is what I am trying to do too (please, feel completely and absolutely free to suggest any improvements in my answer). Bear in mind that the OP is happy with CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls performance and he was just inquiring about how good was doing that. As I understand from your comments, you think that this is a right proceeding? I disagree with that and invite you to read the two links in my answer (MSDN and SO post, Jon Skeet's answer).

Comment: I neither agree nor disagree but offer a different perspective. I just thought that from a different angle, suppose two threads are created, and the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls is still false, yet both threads are accessing the UI, is this still a positive thing? Programming is a constant learning curve, I still have a long way to go! Anyway I'm not criticising you in anyway, like I said, just offering an alternative.

Comment: I think that you haven't still understood my point. I will intend to be clearer: no, CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls is not an option. If you use the backgroundworker you have to know what you are doing, that is, creating a new thread different than the main/GUI one. You CANNOT access GUI elements from the backgroundworker thread (unless you avoid the errors to be triggered, what the aforementioned flag does, what is completely and absolutely wrong). This is what my answer said: update the label OUTSIDE the backgroundworker thread; and this is what your answer says...

Comment: ... and this is what the other answers says too. But the difference between you both is that you are not explaining anything, even I am not sure that you know what you are proposing. Your answer fits exactly on what I said (although without explanations) and that's why I didn't see the exact point (additionally the main problem wasn't addressed). To apply what your propose, the OP's code has to be completely changed (what he doesn't want). The other answer delivers the same (outside the backgroundworker thread) but by respecting the code structure of the OP (but again with not too clear ideas)

Comment: I get what you're saying and your answer stated more accurately what the OP wanted. The last line of my answer says 'eliminating your need to CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls' which is for me saying that you don't need to do this any more if you used this method. Agree that it was not as clear as yours.

Comment: Not exactly clearer, better: different. My answer was stating that you cannot use this flag under absolutely any circumstance. And was written a while before than yours that's why I didn't understand the exact point of your answer, but well... I guess that this discussion has been worthy. As far as I don't want to promote certain attitudes (as the one shown by this OP) and has deleted my answer, you are free to include part of what I said in your answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is a single line and works.

```
Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = "Meow")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of code on your Form.Load, it should be fine.

`Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`