# How to change textbox.text while in backgroundworker?

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I just want to change an textbox text while I am in the backgroundworker.
What I have is:

```
Private Sub ...

 Dim powershellWorker As New BackgroundWorker
        AddHandler powershellWorker.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_DoWork

        powershellWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

 If stuff <> "lol" Then
            test.Text = stuff

End Sub
```

It gives me the error: "Invalid thread -border operation" (google translated)

Comment: UI components can only be updated on the thread that created them.  Use the Textbox's `.Invoke()` method to do this from a background thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.net setting values to labels inside a backgroundworker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844490/vb-net-setting-values-to-labels-inside-a-backgroundworker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change most control properties from a thread other than the thread in which the control was created.

Check if invoke is required, i.e. the current code is executing on a thread other than the thread in which the control (TextBox test) was created. If `test.InvokeRequired` is true, then you should Invoke the call.

```
Private Sub ...
    Dim powershellWorker As New BackgroundWorker
    AddHandler powershellWorker.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundWorker1_DoWork

    powershellWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    If stuff <> "lol" Then
        If test.InvokeRequired Then  
            test.Invoke(Sub() test.Text = stuff)
        Else
            test.Text = stuff
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You can automate the invoke required pattern with this extension method:

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal control As Control, action As MethodInvoker)
    If control.InvokeRequired Then
        control.Invoke(action)
    Else
        action()
    End If
End Sub
```

Then your code could be simplified to:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    If stuff <> "lol" Then
        test.InvokeIfRequired(Sub() test.Text = stuff)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried all - and it just works beautiful! thx alot dude! Well, one little more question: How to start an timer in backgroundworker? "Timer2.Invoke(Sub() Timer2.Start())" sadly doesnt work.

Comment: Found an solution for timer start :) "timerclick.Invoke(Sub() timerclick.PerformClick())" Just click an button who starts the timer for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is brief and seems to work fine:

```
Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = "MEOW")
```