# VB.Net Check Combobox.Text from background worker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, backgroundworker

I'm running the following code in a `BackgroundWorker` in the `DoWork` routine

```
 Dim P As String
        Dim B As Integer

        P = "Verifying User Inputs"
        B = B + 1

        If SubjectName.Text = "" Then
            P = "No Subject Name Entered"
            InputValidate.ReportProgress(B, P)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
        Else
            B = B + 1
        End If

        If AgencyReferrer.Text = "" Or AgencyReferrer.Text = "Configure In Settings" Then
            P = "No Agency Of Referrer Selected"
            InputValidate.ReportProgress(B, P)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
        Else
            B = B + 1
        End If
```

`SubjectName` is a `Textbox` and `AgencyReferrer` is a `Combobox`.

The `Texbox` part of the code completes without any issues, but the `Combobox` part fails saying:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'AgencyReferrer' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

I can't understand how a `Texbox` is treated differently to a `Combobox` in respects to just checking what the text value is.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can pass arguments to the DoWork method which in this case could be the text of those controls.

Comment: I don't see any reason for that code to be in a BackgroundWorker.  If you do use a BackgroundWorker, don't access GUI controls — you get inconsistent results, which you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access or update *most* Controls' members across thread boundaries. In some cases, accessing `TextBox.Text` may fail, in most cases it will work. It is not guaranteed to work.

Without changing too much code, you can get the ComboBox working by using `Control.Invoke()`. Even though the TextBox Text property is working, you should invoke that call as well.

```
Dim P As String
Dim B As Integer

Dim agencyReferrerText = AgencyReferrer.Invoke(New Func(Of String)(Function() AgencyReferrer.Text))

P = "Verifying User Inputs"
B = B + 1

If SubjectName.Text = "" Then
    P = "No Subject Name Entered"
    InputValidate.ReportProgress(B, P)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
Else
    B = B + 1
End If

If agencyReferrerText = "" Or agencyReferrerText = "Configure In Settings" Then
    P = "No Agency Of Referrer Selected"
    InputValidate.ReportProgress(B, P)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
Else
    B = B + 1
End If
```

Invoking these calls can be cumbersome, so see [How to change textbox.text while in backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230640/how-to-change-textbox-text-while-in-backgroundworker/38231964#38231964) about ways to automate the Invoke-If-Required pattern. You can do similar for retrieving properties.